# make question appear in the "active" list under Top Questions

Tags: discussion

I wonder what will make the question appear in the "active" list under Top Questions?

Will any action at all make the question appear in that list? (including trivial ones like up votes)

Or must it be selected actions like posting a comment/edit/answer?

Comment: Upvotes and comments won't bump a question up, while edits and answers certainly will.

Comment: See
[What can cause my question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped) at meta.SO
(or the [tag-wiki for bumping](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info)).